# How do I change the transaction settings for Spring Data repositories globally?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-aop

I'm using Spring Data for my application repositories.

```
interface MyUserRepository extends JpaRepository<MyUser, Long> { … }
```

Spring data is adding transactional for repositories by default but with `Propagation.REQUIRED` if I'm not mistaken. How I can set `Propagation.MANDATORY` for all repositories like in AOP. I don't want to set annotation for every repository.

Idea behind this is to forbid using repositories out of transactional scope so they could be used only through services. I'm using AOP for other services but its not working correctly for repositories as they are already proxied.

Comment: AOP works for repository proxies as Spring will just add advices to the already existing proxy chain. See the application of a `CustomizableTraceInterceptor` in [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/interceptors/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/interceptors/ApplicationConfiguration.java#L30).

Comment: Spring AOP is not working for me. I'm getting: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30

Comment: You must not set `proxy-target-class` to `true` as this will try (as the name suggest) proxy the target class which is a JDK proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom repository base interface and annotate that with the settings you need:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {

}
```

Now let all of your application repositories extend that base repository interface and you'll be good to go.